# python script instead of VBscript in QTP

Tags: python, qtp

can python scripts be used instead of vbscript in QTP, if so, please put some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no, it looks like it's VBScript only.

Long answer: Assuming you mean HP QuickTest Professional, [its summary on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_QuickTest_Professional#Languages) only lists VBScript as a supported scripting language, and the [current Microfocus UFT website](https://software.microfocus.com/en-us/software/uft/feature) (the new name for the product, it appears) mentions that it's scriptable but doesn't indicate the language.

[This Github gist in Python](https://gist.github.com/bulkan/188917) demonstrates you could run UFT tests by starting them off with Python, but that's not the same as being to script the tool itself in Python.